# angular js - specify host name of Rails api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have angular application which interacts with Rails API which is hosted on other domain.

how and where we should keep the target application host name so that it is available to whole angular application and then we can use that to access Rails API

For ex.

I have localhost:8080 on angular and Rails API on localhost:3000 so that in angular i want to save localhost:3000 so that it is available in whole app.

also how we can set depending on environment(dev/prod)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detailed configuration given in angularjs for multiple environments.

[Angularjs config](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/5)

Comment: I did not get this part but can you help me to understand this, can you create html.haml file in angular? so that interpolation can work.  <!-- Our app content -->
    div{'ng-view' => ""}
     :javascript
       angular.module('myApp.config', [])
       = .constant('myConfig', #{CONFIG[Rails.env]})  
       %script{:src => "scripts/app.js"}